# setState not being executed maybe

Tags: reactjs, async-await, setstate

I have a component that fetches a list of items from an API on a button click. name state variable comes from the input box. Code of my handleSubmit method is:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  this.setState({
    fetching: true
  })    
  fetch("https://example.com/v2/sites/list/"+this.state.name, {
    method: 'GET',
    })
    .then(response => async(response) => { 
    await response.json()
    this.setState({
      names: response.json()["items"],
      fetching: false,
      fetched: true
    })
    toast.success(<NotifySuccess />)
  })
  .catch(error => toast.error(<NotifyFailure />));
}
```

On fetched state value being set to true, in my render method, i am trying to render a alert box having names value in it through portals but it seems setState is not working as expected. No alert box appears  and on inspection of component through React developer tool, fetched state value is not being updated to true. Why is it not being updated? Plus, when i set it to true myself using developer tool, an alert box appears with empty value. I clicked ok to close it but it opens again. Have to press ok button again. So alert box also appears two times. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@CertainPeformance is absolutely right, just adding a bit of a cleaner approach in case you can make handleSubmit an async function.

```
async handleSubmit(event) {
...
try {
 const response = await fetch("https://example.com/v2/sites/list/" + 
    this.state.name, {
    method: 'GET',
 })
 const { items } = await response.json()
 this.setState({
     names: items,
     fetching: false,
     fetched: true
 })
 toast.success(<NotifySuccess />)
} catch (error) {
 toast.error(<NotifyFailure />)
};
```

Comment: not working. Shouldn't there be need to add .json() to the fetch?

Comment: Sorry, yeah, i got it wrong with the API fetch. Just updated it, check it out now.

Comment: thanks man, it worked. But now facing another problem.as i mentioned i was getting alert box two times, now i am getting it even more times and seems like keeps on increasing. can't even change name state value using the input box, alerts box keeps on appearing.

Comment: One think I just noticed and it's worth to point out is that you can only consume once the response.json() otherwise you will encounter an error.

Comment: That alert box issue looks related to a loop of renders, checkout your component life cycle.

Answer (score 1):

The `response` is a Promise. Awaiting it in one section of the code doesn't transform that same variable into the resolve value. You need to assign the result of `await`ing it into a variable, which *will* hold the resolve value, then pass that to `setState`:

```
fetch("https://example.com/v2/sites/list/" + this.state.name, {
    method: 'GET',
})
    .then(response => async (response) => {
        const result = await response.json();
        this.setState({
            names: result.items,
            fetching: false,
            fetched: true
        })
        toast.success(<NotifySuccess />)
    })
    .catch(error => toast.error(<NotifyFailure />));
```

Comment: not working. I had this same approach before the current code. Didn't work.